# The "about me" placeholder contains a malicious URL

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

This is the placeholder text everyone sees in the edit tab of a profile if the "about me" section is empty (**emphasis** mine):

> BY DAY: Alt-Rock Ninja Cowgirl at Veridian Dynamics.
>
> BY NIGHT: I write code and code rights for **penalcoders.org**, an awesome
>   non-profit that will totally take your money at that link. My kids are
>   cuter than yours.
>
> FOR FUN: C+ Jokes, Segway Roller Derby, NYT Sat. Crosswords (in
>   Sharpie!), Ostrich Grooming.
>
> "If you see scary things, look for the helpers-you'll always see
>   people helping."-Fred Rogers

If you actually follow that URL, you'll be redirected to a random spammy site. I've been redirected to a site that tries to get me to install an "updated version of Chrome", which is almost certainly malware.

It's not very likely that someone follows the link as it is not clickable, but it can certainly happen due to curiosity. Some users might suspect SE to have hidden an easter egg there.

Mentioning a URL in the profile placeholder that SE doesn't control and that leads to potentially harmful sites is just not a good idea, even if the chance of people following that link is small. The URL should be changed to a domain that is more trustworthy or just removed entirely.

Comment: Yep, its one of those unowned sites. Maybe the owner sold it and SE never updated it? And its Chinese so it might be from China

Comment: @UniKitty Actually it's owned, bought about a month ago.

Comment: @ShadowWizard someone probably bought it because SE linked it

Comment: Well, I can't find any reference that such site ever existed, so I would guess this is a bad attempt at a joke by the developer writing the code.

Comment: I don't understand. Does SE intentially make this?

Comment: What on earth... is this _really_ the placeholder text? Good grief.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yup, that's a nuisance. Replacing in the next build with something that will never resolve and cannot be bought by a spammer.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers which is why the new URL already involves example.org... (or will, when we deploy)

Comment: "I write code samples and examples for example.com?" ;)

Comment: Great! (But example.org does resolve)

Comment: Just be meta..reference an SO URL and pull the money grabbing joke (irrelevant at that point, unless there is a donate button somewhere here).