# Is this a Community meme?

Tags: discussion

So... after some time and some profiles visited, I've seen way too many times something like this:

> By day: *database analyser and programmer*
>   By night: *007 on a mission*

and I'm honestly asking myself if this is an actual meme.

If so, what is it related to?

Comment: I'm just wondering what the `007` means

Comment: James Bond 007 :D

Comment: [Relevant Vine](https://vine.co/v/eYb7OlQuxIg) (and one of my favorites)

Comment: [Funny](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259753/the-about-me-placeholder-contains-a-malicious-url). :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's just because the placeholder text for the About Me section (which is shown when it's empty) follows that same pattern:

> [image: About Me Placeholder]

Although the placeholder has them in reverse order (the funny one is by day, and the serious one is by night).

Comment: About 1800 on SO: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/490628

Comment: I didn't even read it the first time D: